# CV with (adjustable) sidebar over mulitple pages

Tags: tcolorbox, cv, sidebar

I have been trying to create a CV in latex with a gray sidebar that runs over multiple pages. On the first, I would like it to be a little wide (~0.3 sidewidth) with text inside and on the other pages, I would like it to be empty and have wide ~0.1 side width.

This is what I tried (see below), but it doesn't seem to work.
In addition, I get the error that it can't find the `tcbskins.code.tex` file. If I comment that part out, I run into trouble with the enhanced option for the colorboxes.

Any help would be much appreciated!

========================================================================

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,matrix}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% define length
\newlength\cvmargin
\setlength\cvmargin{1cm}

% define more lengths
\newlength\cvsidewidth
\setlength\cvsidewidth{0.3\paperwidth}

\newlength\cvmainwidth
\setlength\cvmainwidth{\paperwidth-\cvsidewidth-4\cvmargin}

%Change titles part CV
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesection}{1em}{}


\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

\newtcolorbox{minipageside}{colback=lightgray,breakable,boxsep=\cvmargin,boxrule=0pt,width=\cvsidewidth+2\cvmargin,height=\paperheight,enhanced,spread inwards,arc=0mm}

\newtcolorbox{minipagemain}{breakable,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,width=\cvmainwidth,arc=0mm}

% set a4paper width minimal options
\usepackage[margin=\cvmargin,noheadfoot,a4paper]{geometry}

%Define inside CV
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}

\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{65,105,225}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%      Contents sidebar      %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipageside}
        % contents
        \section*{\huge{Name}}
        email \\
        \vspace{1em}
        \textit{Institution}\\ 
        Address \\
        Address



        \section*{Research Interest}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item 2 
            \item 3
            \item 4
        \end{itemize}           
\end{minipageside}%
\vspace*{\fill}
\hspace{\cvmargin}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%      Rest of the CV        %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipagemain}
\section*{Research positions}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2017--today & {\bf Postdoctoral researcher }
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2012--2017 &  PhD in Theoretical Physics \\ 
& \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Thesis & Title\\
    Advisor & Professor X
\end{tabular} \\[5pt]
2010--2012 & MSc \\
& \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Thesis & Title \\
    Advisor & Professor Y
\end{tabular} \\[5pt]
2009 & Exchange, University \\ [5pt]
2007-2010 & BSc 
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publication}
\section*{Publications}
\subsection*{Refereed publications in physics journals}

\subsection*{Other publications}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{References}
Prof X \\
Prof Y \\
Prof Z

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Invited seminar presentations}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Conferences \& workshops}
\subsection*{Invited presentations}


\subsection*{Contributed presentations}

\subsection*{Attended conferences}

\subsection*{Schools}

\subsection*{Professional development conferences}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Teaching experience}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Awards}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Fellowships \& grants}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Referee services}
Refereed for ....


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Services}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Outreach \& diversity}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{minipagemain}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a proposal.

I understand that you want to have all pages divided in two vertical sections, the left side bar and the main text. And you want that the side bar has two differents widths for front page and other pages.

What I propose to use is `paracol` package to make these vertical divisions. You can use `\columnratio` parameter to control the relative width of both sections.

The main drawback of this proposal is that you have to control what's included in front page and what after it. To my knowledge is not possible to change the width of differents parts of a `tcolorbox` so you need to do it by hand.

Following code shows an example, the "front" page uses a `\columnratio{.3}` and other pages fixes it to 0.2. Change it to your taste. After that, the front page is formed by a `tcolorbox` which occupies the whole textheight and some text on the right. You'll have to do some trials to decide what is shown in this page. For second and further pages, as left `tcolorbox` is breakable, you won't have to worry about page breaking.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,matrix}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% define length
\newlength\cvmargin
\setlength\cvmargin{1cm}

% define more lengths
\newlength\cvsidewidth
\setlength\cvsidewidth{0.3\paperwidth}

\newlength\cvmainwidth
\setlength\cvmainwidth{\paperwidth-\cvsidewidth-4\cvmargin}

%Change titles part CV
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesection}{1em}{}


\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}

\newtcolorbox{minipageside}{colback=lightgray,breakable,boxsep=\cvmargin,boxrule=0pt,width=\cvsidewidth+2\cvmargin,height=\paperheight,enhanced,spread inwards,arc=0mm}

\newtcolorbox{minipagemain}{breakable,boxsep=0pt,boxrule=0pt,width=\cvmainwidth,arc=0mm}

% set a4paper width minimal options
\usepackage[margin=\cvmargin,noheadfoot,a4paper]{geometry}

%Define inside CV
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}

\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{65,105,225}

\begin{document}

%Front page
\columnratio{.3}
\begin{paracol}{2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%      Contents sidebar      %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray, height=\textheight]
        \section*{\huge{Name}}
        email \\
        \vspace{1em}
        \textit{Institution}\\ 
        Address \\
        Address
        \section*{Research Interest}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item 2 
            \item 3
            \item 4
        \end{itemize}           
\end{tcolorbox}
\switchcolumn  %<--------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%      Rest of the CV        %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Research positions}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2017--today & {\bf Postdoctoral researcher }
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2012--2017 &  PhD in Theoretical Physics \\ 
& \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Thesis & Title\\
    Advisor & Professor X
\end{tabular} \\[5pt]
2010--2012 & MSc \\
& \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Thesis & Title \\
    Advisor & Professor Y
\end{tabular} \\[5pt]
2009 & Exchange, University \\ [5pt]
2007-2010 & BSc 
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1em}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publication}
\section*{Publications}
\subsection*{Refereed publications in physics journals}
\subsection*{Other publications}

\section*{References}
Prof X \\
Prof Y \\
Prof Z

\section*{Invited seminar presentations}
\section*{Conferences \& workshops}
\subsection*{Invited presentations}
\subsection*{Contributed presentations}
\subsection*{Attended conferences}
\subsection*{Schools}
\subsection*{Professional development conferences}
\section*{Teaching experience}
\section*{Awards}
\section*{Fellowships \& grants}
\section*{Referee services}
Refereed for ....

\section*{Services}
\section*{Outreach \& diversity}
\end{paracol}
%%%% End of front page

%%% Second page and ...
\columnratio{.2}
\begin{paracol}{2}
%Gray margin column, breakable
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, colback=lightgray]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\switchcolumn %<----------
% Main contents of second and further pages
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]