# How to extend textblock to next page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, page, textpos

I am trying to update my CV but my textblock need to extend to next page. As you can see in the image the textblock breaks and it doesn't change page.

[image]

Im new to Latex but I also know from my research that textblock won't "detect" next page with `textpos`.
My code:

```
\begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace{13pt}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\givenprofilepic}{}}{}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
\clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);

    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) 
  {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\givenprofilepic}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

 {\Huge\color{mainblue}\givencvname}

 \begin{flushright}
 {\Large\color{black!80}\givencvjobtitle}
 \end{flushright}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
 \begin{tabular}{p{0.3cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \givencvdate\\}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \givencvaddress\\}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givennumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & 
 \givennumberphone\\}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \href{\givencvsite} 
 {\textcolor{cerulean}\givencvsite}\\}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvsiteone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & 
 \href{\givencvsiteone}{\textcolor{cerulean}\givencvsiteone}\\}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\givencvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\givencvmail} 
 {\givencvmail}\\ \\}
 \end{tabular}

 \profilesection{Skills}{4.6cm}
 \givensoftware\\

 \profilesection{Software}{3.4cm}\\
 \givenskill
 \giventextskill\\

 \profilesection{Languages}{2.7cm}\\
 \givenlang

 \noindent
 \scriptsize
 \noindent

 \end{flushleft}
 \end{textblock}
```

Also I am thinking of extending the `rectangle` as you can see in the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node [rectangle, fill=asidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9.80cm, minimum 
  height=\paperheight] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I am unable to extend the `rectangle` which would be a fine solution by me. Any idea?

Comment: Can it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448110/1952

Answer (score 0):

A textblock will never break over a new page, because the goal of the `textpos` package is to place a box, as an unbroken unit, at a specific position on the page.  The textblock will grow in height, as required by its content, but it stays as a single box.

It's not completely clear, from your description, what it is you're aiming for, but if part of it is to have material in the left margin automatically page-break at the same time as material in the main block of text, then that would be seriously hard.  As it happens, TeX really isn't set up for that.  It's not impossible (measuring boxes in the `\output` routine, blah blah blah), but it would be challenging.

If you can clarify what it is you're aiming to do, people here might be able to suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: I think this is a CV template called [Twenty seconds](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj) that internally use `textpos`.

Comment: Aha! It does look like it, yes.  I notice on the github page for it that ‘This template has been designed to create a "one-page" résumé and is therefore not suitable to create a curriculum of more than one-page.’